# Execute Scripts Over Serial Connection Using Perl and cmd

Tags: command-line, switch, perl, serial-port

I want to execute a script via a serial connection COM6 and have said script clear a switch without credentials.  I can send the file but the script does not execute.  Is there a specific command or application I should use outside of cmd?  I'm on Windows 10 have bash and putty.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a quiet vague, what do you mean by credentials? You don't need credentials to use the serial port, you just need to make sure that the user who runs the script has rights to access the serial port. I will try to answer best I can given the limited information.

You can do most of your work with Perl and serial port using [Win32::SerialPort](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::SerialPort)

Since you are talking about switches, I assume you are setting some sort of contact closures for a device you have connected to the port?

You may also want to refer to [Perl Pack Tutorial or perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html) for that purpose, as in most cases you will need to set individual binary bits on each chunk of data you send to the board for setting switches.

I would recommend using parallel port for persistently setting bits if thats what you need. Refer to [Device::ParallelPort](https://metacpan.org/pod/Device::ParallelPort)